# methods inheritance in python

Tags: python, oop, methods

```
class Field(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.drunks = {}

    def addDrunk(self, drunk, loc):
        if drunk in self.drunks:
            raise ValueError('Duplicate drunk')
        else:
            self.drunks[drunk] = loc

    def moveDrunk(self, drunk):
        if not drunk in self.drunks:
            raise ValueError('Drunk not in field')
        xDist, yDist = drunk.takeStep()
        currentLocation = self.drunks[drunk]
        #use move method of Location to get new location
        self.drunks[drunk] = currentLocation.move(xDist, yDist)

    def getLoc(self, drunk):
        if not drunk in self.drunks:
            raise ValueError('Drunk not in field')
        return self.drunks[drunk]


    import random


def walk(f, d, numSteps):
    start = f.getLoc(d)
    for s in range(numSteps):
        f.moveDrunk(d)
    return(start.distFrom(f.getLoc(d)))
```

i'm learning python.I saw this code and i couldn't understand why the walk function can use the moveDrunk() method? shouldn't  raise an error because moveDrunk() is from Field class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass an instance of the `Field` class (`f`) as an argument:

```
def walk(f, d, numSteps):
         ^
```

Comment: Isn't f just an argument? Why f is an isntance of Field?

Comment: @lucas: That's what it looks like it should be. You should be passing an instance of `Field` as the first argument. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: so if i don't pass a instance of Field as the first argument will raise an error?

Comment: @lucas: As long as `f` implements `getLoc` and `moveDrunk`, then it'll work.